# Building ffmpeg for Windows with MSYS and MinGW

Tags: windows-xp, ffmpeg, mingw

I am trying to build ffmpeg for windows (Xp - SP2) as given [here](http://www.gooli.org/blog/building-ffmpeg-for-windows-with-msys-and-mingw/).

```
./configure -–extra-cflags=”-mno-cygwin -mms-bitfields” -–extra-ldflags=”-Wl, -add-stdcall-alias” -–enable-memalign-hack -–enable-shared -–disable-static -–target-os=mingw32
```

The above command is placed in a `myconfig` file as instructed and when i run `./myconfig`, the following error is displayed:

```
Broken Shell detected. Trying alternatives.
Trying Shell bash
Unknown option "-–extra-cflags=-mno-cygwin".
```

As suggested in the link i tried various options but still i was not able to succeed.

My environment is Win XP with:

- MinGW-5.1.6,
- bash-2.05b-MSYS,
- MSYS-1.0.10,
- ffmpeg-0.5

**EDIT:**

After certain changes in the above command by referring [howto](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#build) i was able to successfully run the *make* command and i found the following DLL's in their respective directory

- ffmpeg\libavcodec\avcodec-51.dll
- ffmpeg\libavformat\avformat-51.dll
- ffmpeg\libavutil\avutil-49.dll

But i didn't see any ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe file :(

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: I've flagged this as belonging on Stack Overflow as it's a programming issue. Head on over and create & associate your accounts so you'll have ownership if it moves.

Comment: i do have an account in stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Sri - that's all right then ;) I should have checked your profile - sorry.

Comment: Really, doesn't this belong on StackOverflow?

Comment: what are the last few lines after running "make clean && make"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ramiro's [FFmpeg for Windows](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/) site gives much better step by step instructions, and has a community forum that you can ask questions on if the Wiki doesn't answer your question already.

Comment: The link is broken. Do you have working solution for 64 bit windows?

Comment: for cross compiling (for 64-bit windows) see https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers also here is a forum for windows: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/ which may be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Possibly off topic, but I wrote a
[script for Cygwin](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/install-ffmpeg.sh)
to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the latest version from there but to use libfdk_aac they as to configure ffmpeg, I tried c:\FFMPEG\bin>ffmpeg  --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-nonfree but it throws "Unrecognized option '-enable-libfdk_aac'. Error splitting the argument list: Option not found" . Thoughts?

Comment: So, I cannot directly add a codec to existing FFMPEG exe? I am sorry I don't get your point here on how to use your script :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally I succeeded to build ffmpeg on windows with this blog http://www.finalmediaplayer.com/source.html

You may also want to add [lame](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/lame/3.99/lame-3.99.5.tar.gz/download) and [x264](ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/videolan/x264/snapshots/x264-snapshot-20130303-2245-stable.tar.bz2) to your build.

1. Extract the tar to /ffmpeg/libraries
2. `./configure --prefix=/ffmpeg/olibs --enable-static --disable-shared`
3. `make`
4. `make install`

Additionals libraries:

- FAAC http://downloads.sourceforge.net/faac/faac-1.28.tar.gz
- FDK-AAC http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/files/fdk-aac/fdk-aac-0.1.1.tar.gz/download

Reconfigure your ffmpeg again with the options: `--enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac`