# JWPlayer & Thumbnails preview?

Tags: thumbnails, jwplayer

I have a website that hosts a lot of videos thanks to the JW Player, and I want to add the preview thumbnails, but I don't know how to do. I found an article http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407439-adding-preview-thumbnails but no tutorial about how to create the .vtt files & generate the sprites.

Someone knows how to do this easily ?

Comment: See my comment here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022006/generate-all-the-files-vtt-sprite-for-the-tooltip-thumbnails-options-of-jwp