# Generate a thumbnail image from an uploaded video file using Django

Tags: python, django, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I use Django and django-rest-framework.

I need to implement a rest-api to upload a video file.

This is easy but I need also to generate a thumbnail image when the video is uploaded.

I googled about it and I found [django-videothumbs](https://github.com/macmichael01/django-videothumbs) app but it is not recommended to use it in production.

Is there something that I can use/see about generating a thumbnail from a video file using Django?

Comment: [Might already be answered here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789652/how-to-create-video-thumbnails-with-python-and-gstreamer/16478342#16478342)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563697/create-video-thumbnail-from-video-source-in-python) answer.