# How to create thumbnails for videos using django?

Tags: django, video, thumbnails

I am displaying my videos in my django site. I want to display those video like thumbnails, but I don't know how to create thumbnails for my videos.
I have stored my videos through admin module.
here is my code

models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='static/gallery/videos',
                             null=False,
                             help_text=_("video file")
                            )
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Video

admin.site.register(Video)
```

Any one help me for how to store my video thumbnails format in db or how to display my retrieved videos in thumbnail format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can add a nullable file field to store thumbnail and fill it manually in `save` method or using a model save signal.

You can use answers to these questions to find out how to generate those thumbnails:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1843043/1823497

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27565893/1823497

Since generating thumbnails can be a time consuming job, i recommend to use a [celery task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html) to do it in background without blocking your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

1)install opencv-python
2)check if file is video or image
3)i couldnt figure out to videocapture from memory so write the file to disk then load using cv2.videocapture
4)take first frame and write to disk
5)again load image from disk and save it in database
6)delete the temporary files in disk

```
import mimetypes
import cv2
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from pathlib import Path

    

    new_story=Story(user=user, file=file)
    file_type, t =mimetypes.guess_type(str(file))
    
    if file_type.split('/')[0] == "image":
        new_story.save() 
        return Storymutation(story=new_story)
    path = default_storage.save('video.mp4', ContentFile(file.read()))
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(f"./media/{path}")
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    cv2.imwrite(f"./media/{path}.jpeg", image)
    thumbnail = default_storage.open(f"{path}.jpeg")
    new_story.thumbnail=thumbnail
    new_story.save()
    thumbnail.close()
    del image, vidcap
    default_storage.delete(path)
    default_storage.delete(f"{path}.jpeg")
    return Storymutation(story=new_story)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: sorry just joined stk

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of generating a thumbnail. You can adjust the code to your needs for a Django project.

I am using [ffmpeg-python: Python bindings for FFmpeg](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)

```
import ffmpeg

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile


with NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_video_file:
    # user_video is a django model instance with video and thumbnail FileFields
    in_memory_file = user_video.video

    if in_memory_file.multiple_chunks():
        for chunk in in_memory_file.chunks():
            temp_video_file.write(chunk)
    else:
        temp_video_file.write(in_memory_file.read())

    try:
        probe = ffmpeg.probe(temp_video_file.name)
        time = float(probe["streams"][0]["duration"]) // 2
        width = probe["streams"][0]["width"]

        with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".jpg") as temp_thumbnail_file:
            (
                ffmpeg.input(temp_video_file.name, ss=time)
                .filter("scale", width, -1)
                .output(temp_thumbnail_file.name, vframes=1)
                .overwrite_output()
                .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
            )

    except ffmpeg.Error as e:
        # do whatever you want with the error
        error = e.stderr.decode()
    else:
        # you can also just return the thumbnail e.g
        # return ContentFile('name_you_like.jpg', temp_thumbnail_file.read())
        user_video.thumbnail.save(
            Path(temp_thumbnail_file.name).name,
            ContentFile(temp_thumbnail_file.read()),
            save=True,
        )
```