# Extracting thumbnails with FFMPEG is super slow on large video files?

Tags: performance, ffmpeg, extract, video-thumbnails

I extract thumbnails from a `.MOV` file using FFMPEG on Linus (Debian 64bit).

The file I extract the thumbnail from is about 430 Megabytes large.

I use the following command to do so:

```
ffmpeg -i 'largeVideoFile.mov' -ss 00:14:37 -vframes 1 'thumbnail.jpg'
```

It takes well over 3 minutes for a single frame to be extracted.

How can I speed it up?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[I found this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534835/fastest-way-to-extract-a-specific-frame-from-a-video-php-ffmpeg-anything), which suggests that one should use fast seeking to increase performance by simply defining `-ss`in front of  `-i` rather than the other way around.

So my command now looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:14:37 -i 'largeVideoFile.mov' -vframes:v 1 'thumbnail.jpg'
```

Notice that the arrangement of the parameters have been changed,
starting with `-ss`and time, followed by `-i` and source file, and finally `-vframes:v`, `1` and the destination path.

The time is down to about 1 second which is nice.